# How to set node link colour based on node name?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have set the colour of nodes in a d3.js tree based on the node name.  Now I want to set the node link colour based on the node name.

[image]

I have tried unsuccessfully using:

```
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d){
        return 1;
      })
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .attr("stroke", function(d){ 
        return linkColor(d.name);
        });
```

and the function with switch further down:

```
function linkColor(node_name) {
    switch (node_name)
    {
      case 'Second A': 
        return 'red';
        break;
      case 'Second B':
        return 'green';
        break;
      case 'Second C': 
        return 'purple';
        break;
      case 'Second D':
        return 'gold';
    }
}
```

Note that I can set the color of all links with `.attr('style','stroke: red;')`

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7jhzc98/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the data bound to the paths, which is `links`, there is no property called `name`. However, you have that property in the `source` and `target` objects.

Therefore, you have to choose sources or targets. For instance, using the targets:

```
.style("stroke", function(d){ 
    return linkColor(d.target.name);
});
```

Also, use `style`, not `attr`, because you already have a CSS for those paths. Finally, you should get rid of that awful `switch` block: just use D3 scales.

Here is your updated code:

```js
var treeData = [{
  "name": "Top Level",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Second A",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third A"
    }, {
      "name": "Third B"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Second B",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third C"
    }, {
      "name": "Third D"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Second C",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third E"
    }, {
      "name": "Third F"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Second D",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third G"
    }, {
      "name": "Third H"
    }, ]
  }, ]
}];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");


// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "#C0C0C0" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.name == "Top Level") {
        return d._children ? "blue" : "#fff";
      }
      if (d.name == "Second A") {
        return d._children ? "red" : "#fff";
      }
      if (d.name == "Second B") {
        return d._children ? "green" : "#fff";
      }
      if (d.name == "Second C") {
        return d._children ? "purple" : "#fff";
      }
      if (d.name == "Second D") {
        return d._children ? "gold" : "#fff";
      }
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      if (d.name == "Top Level") {
        return "blue";
      }
      if (d.name == "Second A") {
        return "red";
      }
      if (d.name == "Second B") {
        return "green";
      }
      if (d.name == "Second C") {
        return "purple";
      }
      if (d.name == "Second D") {
        return "gold";
      }
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return 1;
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return linkColor(d.target.name);
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}


// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

function linkColor(node_name) {
  switch (node_name) {
    case 'Second A':
      return 'red';
      break;
    case 'Second B':
      return 'green';
      break;
    case 'Second C':
      return 'purple';
      break;
    case 'Second D':
      return 'gold';
  }
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks Gerardo.

Comment: I looked at d3 scales and it seems to be the way to go.  Though I'm not at all sure how to implement it in the fiddle example, so I will open a new question.  Basically I want the children from the second level to inherit the the colour from the parent, with the colours graduating down the line on the same palette.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310528/d3-js-tree-how-to-implement-d3-scales-to-have-children-inherit-colour-from-par