# How to implement D3 scales to have children inherit colour from parent with graduations?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3.js tree that have different colours applied to nodes and links.

[image]

The colouring is hardcoded:

```
nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
       .style("fill", function(d) { 
     if(d.name == "Top Level") {
      return d._children ? "blue" : "#fff"; 
      }
    if(d.name == "Second A") {
     return d._children ? "red" : "#fff"; 
    }
      if(d.name == "Second B") {
      return d._children ? "green" : "#fff"; 
      }
    if(d.name == "Second C") {
      return d._children ? "purple" : "#fff"; 
      }
      if(d.name == "Second D") {
      return d._children ? "gold" : "#fff"; 
      }
    })
     .style("stroke", function(d) { 
     if(d.name == "Top Level") {
      return "blue"; 
      }
    if(d.name == "Second A") {
     return "red"; 
    }
      if(d.name == "Second B") {
      return "green"; 
      }
    if(d.name == "Second C") {
      return "purple"; 
      }
      if(d.name == "Second D") {
      return "gold"; 
      }
    });
```

and

```
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d){
        return 1;
      })
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return linkColor(d.target.name);
    });
```

and

```
function linkColor(node_name) {
    switch (node_name)
    {
      case 'Second A': case 'Third A':  case 'Third B': 
        return 'red';
        break;
      case 'Second B': case 'Third C':  case 'Third D': 
        return 'green';
        break;
      case 'Second C': case 'Third E':  case 'Third F': 
        return 'purple';
        break;
      case 'Second D': case 'Third G':  case 'Third H': 
        return 'gold';
    }
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5tpy1db/2/)

Rather than hardcoding the colour of each node and link, I want to implement [d3-scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) to colour the nodes and lines. The solution would have the children 'inherit' their parent's colour along a [graduation of that colour](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic/blob/master/README.md#schemeYlGnBu) automatically given x number of children.

https://www.d3indepth.com/scales/

How can I achieve this?

As always, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale you need is an ordinal scale, like this:

```
var colourScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Top Level","Second A", "Second B", "Second C", "Second D"])
    .range(["blue","red", "green", "purple", "gold"]);
```

Then, you can change this whole thing...

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
    if (d.name == "Top Level") {
        return d._children ? "blue" : "#fff";
    }
    if (d.name == "Second A") {
        return d._children ? "red" : "#fff";
    }
    if (d.name == "Second B") {
        return d._children ? "green" : "#fff";
    }
    if (d.name == "Second C") {
        return d._children ? "purple" : "#fff";
    }
    if (d.name == "Second D") {
        return d._children ? "gold" : "#fff";
    }
})
```

...into just:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
    return colourScale(d.name)
})
```

And also get rid of that `linkColor` function.

Pay attention to the fact that, despite you have linked D3 v5 documentation, you're using D3 v3.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var treeData = [{
  "name": "Top Level",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Second A",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third A"
    }, {
      "name": "Third B"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Second B",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third C"
    }, {
      "name": "Third D"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Second C",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third E"
    }, {
      "name": "Third F"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Second D",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third G"
    }, {
      "name": "Third H"
    }, ]
  }, ]
}];

var colourScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["Top Level", "Second A", "Second B", "Second C", "Second D"])
  .range(["blue", "red", "green", "purple", "gold"]);


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");


// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {



  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "#C0C0C0" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.depth === 2 ? colourScale(d.parent.name) : colourScale(d.name);
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.depth === 2 ? colourScale(d.parent.name) : colourScale(d.name);
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return 1;
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.target.depth === 2 ? colourScale(d.target.parent.name) : colourScale(d.target.name);
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}


// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, that brilliant Gerado, thanks for your answer!  One question though, how would I have all children of a second level parent have the same colour?  For example, Third C and Third D be green, the same as parent Second B?  Ideally, I would like to have the colour graduating down the lineage, but that's probably another question if needed.

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 use a conditional for the third level, so you pass their parent's name to the scale. Check the snippet again.

Comment: How would I handle this in d3.js v4?  I have updated to use var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
   .domain(["MD","Professional", "Leader", "Advocate", "Clinician", "Educator", "Scholar"])
    .range(["blue","red", "green", "purple", "gold", "brown", "silver"]); as scale.ordinal breaks with 4.  But what about .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.depth === 2 ? colourScale(d.parent.name) : colourScale(d.name);
    })  ?? which doesn't work in v4

Comment: The scale is exactly the same, just changing `scale.ordinal` for `scaleOrdinal`. Regarding the hierarchy, there are a lot of changes to be made.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll stay with v3 for the time being ;)